# Is this multiple inheritance? or another syntax for Inherits/Implements like C#?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, interface

I am trying to work out why this works

```
Public Interface IFullService
    Inherits ISerializableObjectLayerService, IVersionService
    <OperationContract()>
    Function StartTrac() As OperationResult(Of Boolean)
    <OperationContract()>
    Function StopTrac() As OperationResult(Of Boolean)
    <OperationContract()>
    Function IsTracRunning() As OperationResult(Of Boolean)
End Interface
```

An interface doesn't allow you to specify that it "implements" another interface, however in my case I needed to state that I have both interfaces, just by chance I put a comma in and entered the other interface, built and ran my unit tests and it works...

Previously I have been trying to follow a single inheritance tree such as

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IFullService
    Inherits IVersionService
    <OperationContract()>
    Function StartTrac() As OperationResult(Of Boolean)
    <OperationContract()>
    Function StopTrac() As OperationResult(Of Boolean)
    <OperationContract()>
    Function IsTracRunning() As OperationResult(Of Boolean)
End Interface

<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IVersionService
    Inherits ISerializableObjectLayerService
    <OperationContract()>
    Function GetVersionsSince(ByVal VersionNumber As Long, IncludeBetas As Boolean) As OperationResult(Of Core.Setting.MemoryBmsReleaseInfo())
End Interface
```

As you can see here the IFullService inherits the IVersionService which then inherits the IVersionService. However in my case I needed a way for something to implement IVersionService without implementing the ISerializableObjectLayerService which is what lead me to my "working" solution.

Unfortunately I can't work out how to find out what exactly this is doing. I have search through stackoverflow, google, msdn and I can't find an example with Inherits ,

Could some guru please provide some information on what exactly this is accomplishing (would be great if you can provide a MSDN link), as I don't like doing something that I don't understand (as it can lead to problem in the future that you can work out :D)

Hopefully this question isn't too noobish :D

Comment: damn, can't answer my own post as I don't have enough "rep"

but here is my answer


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682227/vb-net-multiple-inheritance-in-an-interface

I knew that .NET didn't support Multiple Inheritance, hence this idea worked just puzzled me, so it seems Multiple Inheritance is supported, but only in Interfaces, it is only Classes that don't support multi inheritance.

Wish the MSDN articles on Inherits keyword would have explained this situation. Bah, so sorry for the wasted question, seems my search keywords just hadn't come up with the right result before I posted.

Comment: MSDN does explain this situation: see the [remarks on the Inherits keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yk8s7sk(v=vs.71).aspx). (Though having said that I wouldn't be surprised if there are a bunch of other articles that don't even mention it.)

Comment: Cheers mate, your right, now I am getting the links they are just slapping me in the face, at the time I was trying to just identify it through an example ie. Inherits IType, IType2 so I could find out what it is (believing that MI wasn't supported in .NET) so yeah, searching with the blinkers on didn't help me much :P cheers

Comment: gave you +1 for more rep's (hope that helps:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft docs do mention it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx

> An interface itself can inherit from multiple interfaces.

Edit: Another link (All VB, with example), for an early edition of Visual Studio, but the information still applies.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711871%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Ahh but in C# and no examples ;D either way thanks for the link

Comment: It says the same thing I quoted on the VB page (see tabs at top of page). Link is the same for all tabs.

Comment: all good, thanks for the link, every day we lay down code we learn something new ;D

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, it's **multiple inheritance**.

#### ... of interfaces.

It means that *any `IFullService` **IS A(n)** IVersionService*. (When you see "any A is also a B", that's what "A inherits from B" means.)

Interface inheritance doesn't have any issues like multiple inheritance does, so MI is allowed. :)